# Total variation between $S_n$ and $Z$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the total variation distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is,

$$
TV(\mu,\nu)=\sup_{A\in \mathcal{B}}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|
$$

Let $S_n=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $X_{i}=\pm 1,$ iid $,\forall i=\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $Z$ is the standard normal random variable. In these [notes](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Esouravc/AllLectures.pdf), on page 6, it is claimed that $TV(S_n,Z)=1,\forall n$.

My proof for this is that since the sample space, say $A$, of $S_n$ is countable and discrete for a given $n$. Then $\mu(A)=1$ and $\nu(A)=0$ since $Z$ is a continuous distribution. Is this correct?

If it is, wouldn't the total variation distance between two continuous probability measures be always one?

Comment: It is not the sample space, but the range of $(S_n)$ that is countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is for one discrete and one continuous r.v. so you cannot conclude that the total variation distance between any two continuous distributions is $1$. (What if the two are the same?)

We always have $|\mu (A)-\nu (A)| \leq 1$ and there is  a countable set $A$ with $P(S_n \in A)=1$. So $TV(S_n,Z) \geq |\mu (A)-\nu (A)|=|1-0|=1$.

The total variation distance between a discrete and a continuous distributions is $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and comment!

Comment: Welcome, it is my pleasure. @cookiemonster